# gcc: Link Library In Same Folder As Source Files

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

I'm trying to compile a **C** project using **gcc**. All source files and the .a library file are *in the same folder*. How can I successfully compile the project?

[image]

I've tried:

```
gcc -o test main.c IPT.c logitem_list.c -L -./ -libpt
```

But I receieve error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libpt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The [correct option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) is `-lpt` (not `-libpt`)

Comment: @pmg You are correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specify the directory to `-L` and the 'core' name to `-l`:

```
gcc -o test main.c IPT.c logitem_list.c -L . -lpt
```

When given `-l`*`pt`*, the linker looks for `libpt.a` or `libpt.so` or equivalents (extensions like `.dylib` or `.sl` or `.dll` or `.lib` on other platforms).

The `-L -./` is suggesting that the linker look in a directory called 'dash dot', which is unlikely to exist and isn't where `libpt.a` is found anyway.

Comment: Use the LIBRARY_PATH env variable in your shell .login file to add this automatically by adding a semicolon for linux or mac to the front or end of the path. Example `export LIBRARY_PATH=":/opt/homebrew/lib/"`

Comment: @VrajShah — 'semicolon' --> 'colon' if you're quick

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a static lib, you can also most easily just specify the file directly on the command line.  Remember that a static library is just an indexed archive of object files:

```
gcc -o test main.c IPT.c logitem_list.c ./libpt.a
```

You can also do this with shared libraries, but you probably shouldn't.